Share a port between two containers using pasta network mode in podman
I have a very basic requirement which does not work when using pasta networking mode.
Two containers, container app and container db need to communicate, specifically container app needs to connect to container db on port 3306.
Without pasta, I would simply:
A: put the containers on the same network, and the app container could simply connect to db:3306
B: run the db container with 127.0.0.1:12345:3306, and the app container would connect to host.containers.internal:12345
But when using pasta, neither of these works.
The only way I have figured out to make option B work is running the app container with --network=pasta:-T,12345, but this seems like a complicated solution for an easy problem, and I don't even really want to map the database port to the host, because it is only accessed from within the app container.
Is there a better/simpler way to accomplish this? (without using pods)
